# How many compositions of length n of a number exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Compositions of a number are a way of writing a number as the sum of a sequence of integers.

There are $(2)^{k-1}$ compositions for a number k.

My question is: how many compositions of length n, (n must obviously be less than or equal to k) exist for k?

Thanks

Comment: search for Stars and Bars.

Comment: Look for the Wikipedia page on Composition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \binom{k-1}{n-1}. $$
Any composition can be written uniquely in the form
$$ (1 \square 1 \square 1 \dotsb \square 1), $$
with $k$ "$1$"s and $k-1$ "$\square$"s, with each "$\square$" being either a "$+$" or a "$,$". To find the compositions of length $n$ is the same as choosing $n-1$ of the "$\square$"s to be "$,$"s, and this is, of course, is given by the binomial coefficient.